# valueOf method of Enum

Tags: java, enums

[Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) has a **valueOf** method:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

So, when i have the enum:

```
public enum Basket {
    APPLES, ORANGES, FLOWERS 
}
```

the code

```
Basket b = Basket.valueOf(Basket.class, "APPLES");
```

brings me the same object as does

```
Basket b2 = Basket.APPLES;
```

i.e., **b.equals(b2)** is true out of the two lines above.

What i'm wondering is-- what is

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

good for.

There may be a use of it in the reflect API-- one that i can't put together right now. outside of that, does this method has a specific use? what would be missing, if the class [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) didn't have this method?

Same for the valueOf-with-single parameter-- defined implicitly in [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html):

```
Basket.valueOf("APPLES");
```

is doing the same thing as

```
Basket.valueOf(Basket.class, "APPLES");
```

What's the use?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question a bit - are you trying to determine the difference between the two, or the use cases?

Comment: @Makoto exactly what the Q says-- "whats the use for valueOf"-- what would be missing from the java world if it werent there. see Adi`s answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

is used when you don't know exact Enum type. This is the case if you are writing a generic code. One example is deserializing json to java object. You can get the 'enumType' of a field though reflection and invoke,

`Enum.valueOf(enumClass,fieldValue)`

If you want to see real usage, check,

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream#readEnum
```